# Botón HTML en PHP

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Tengo un problema con la forma de mostrar un botón HTML en PHP.

Este es mi código funcional mostrando el botón:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>clientes/Pagos_controller/pago_credito/<?php echo $contrato->id_contratos_d;?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><span class="fa fa-money"> </span> Depositar: Facilidad de pago</a><br>
```

Y funciona perfectamente, pero las circunstancias hicieron que lo pusiera en una condicional en php, que es la siguiente:

```
<?php if (empty($restan_pago_credito[0]->restante_credito) == 0){ print '<a href="'+base_url()+'clientes/Pagos_controller/pago_credito/'; echo $contrato->id_contratos_d;+'" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">'; } else{ print "<h4><strong>No hay datos registrados</strong></h4>"; } ?>
```

Y salta el error:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: A non-numeric
>   value encountered

Necesito ayuda, lo he intentado casi todo, pero no me sale un resultado éxito, estoy seguro que es la forma de como concatenó el PHP en el HTML de este fragmento PHP (Así sería la forma de describirlo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que estás confundiendo el operador de concatenación de PHP, que es el punto (.), con el + que se usa para concatenar en JavaScript o Python, por ejemplo.

> El error aparece porque estás usando + (adición) en dos cadenas de texto, entonces PHP no puede hacer la respectiva suma.

También tienes algun ; en un lugar incorrecto.

Teniendo en cuenta que empty() entrega un boolean, no necesitas compararlo con 0:

```
<?php 

if (! empty($restan_pago_credito[0]->restante_credito)) {

    print '<a href="' . base_url() . 'clientes/Pagos_controller/pago_credito/';
    echo $contrato->id_contratos_d . '" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">';

} else {

    print "<h4><strong>No hay datos registrados</strong></h4>"; 

} 

?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información y por la pronta respuesta, efectivamente, estaba omitiendo información que gracias a ti ahora conozco.